# Xpages - Value picker UI customization

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to create a custom value picker which can have:

- Same labels
- Can't use simple Domino view value picker as I need to check individual entry for some business criteria
- I want to show a short summary as well to help user distinguish among similar labels (I want to add some formatting to it e.g. label in bold, summary in green small chars)

I can create an Xpage for all such value pickers or I can have a custom data provider. Now, my question is, do I need to create a custom renderer as well to display Label with summary? How do I implement the picker with modal look-n-feel (I am using bootstrap theme)?
Thanks in advance
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 12 of the Extension Library included the code I contributed for Map Picker Data Provider and Collection Picker Data Provider. Implementing data provider outside the Extension Library packages is quite complicated - there are a lot of methods used for getting options etc that are protected, so they need reproducing. They're currently designed to take a label and value only, so they would need extending to take a summary as well.

I don't think the picker can take HTML as a picker option - that would allow you to pass in the formatting for the label and the summary. I've not tried it, but if it was allowed it would impact searching etc, so that makes me suspect it's unlikely.

Creating a renderer with bootstrap look and feel is possible. I'd recommend looking at the Extension Library renderers. It looks like the picker renderers handle the link on the page and separate classes handle the dialog that's displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. One question though, how can we see the extension library code in Designer?

Comment: The source code is available as one of the plugins in the download, srcOpenNTF.zip. I'd recommend installing it into Eclipse, to make it easier to develop with and not affect Domino Designer. The instructions for installing it are on a blog post on OpenNTF http://openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=PWIS-9QZTH2